# Activestate perl 5.14.2.1402 and Perlfect search 3.37 DB_File error on IIS 7

Tags: perl, iis-7, activestate

I am getting an error trying to install Perlfect search after I run `setup.pl`

```
The required DB_File module was not found on your system
```

I've tried following the instructions from the [Perlfect search readme](http://www.perlfect.com/freescripts/search/readme.shtml) and also from [How do I install Perl 5.8 and Perlfect on IIS 7.5? on Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/176321/how-do-i-install-perl-5-8-and-perlfect-on-iis-7-5) but can't get past the step of running the `setup.pl`.

Comment: You have installed [ActiveState's DB_File PPM](http://code.activestate.com/ppm/DB_File/) correct? Actually, looking at that page, it appears that's not possible...

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at [the DB_File PPM page](http://code.activestate.com/ppm/DB_File/) you'll see that [DB_File](http://p3rl.org/DB_File) has not been built for Windows, either 32- or 64-bit. If you look at one of [the build logs](http://ppm4.activestate.com/MSWin32-x86/5.14/1400/P/PM/PMQS/DB_File-1.824.d/log-20110808T023256.txt) you'll see that its because the build is disabled. An [older log](http://ppm4.activestate.com/MSWin32-x86/5.10/1000/P/PM/PMQS/DB_File-1.819.d/log-20090219T081703.txt) reveals that it's disabled because ActiveState knows that Berkeley DB is not available, so the build will fail.

So, you'll need to either find a way to built it yourself, or alternatively see if you can get [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/) to work. According the the Win32 Perl Wiki entry [Install DB File on Strawberry Perl](http://win32.perl.org/wiki/index.php?title=Install_DB_File_on_Strawberry_Perl) that is fairly easy.